# how to make my controllers post to process files with multer npm in frontend vus js and backend nodejs I don't happen recover files in backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, multer

here it is the back end always it tells me undefined to find the file

```js
const mysql = require("mysql");
const Poste = require("../models/post");

// Create and Save a new Poste
exports.create = (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    file: `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}/images/${req.file}`,
  });
  console.log(this.file);

  /*
  // Validate request
  if (!req.body) {
    res.status(400).send({
      message: "Content can not be empty!",
    });
  }

  // Create a Poste
  const poste = new Poste({
    titre: req.body.titre,
    description: req.body.description,
   // image_link: req.bodyimage_link,
    nb_commentaires: req.body.nb_commentaires,
    nb_likes: req.body.nb_likes,
    nb_dislikes: req.body.nb_dislikes,
    user_id: req.body.user_id,
    date_cree: req.body.date_cree,
  });

  // Save Poste in the database
  Poste.create(poste, (err, data) => {
    if (err)
      res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Poste.",
      });
    else res.send(data);
  });
  */
};
```

here it is the front end seen js always I have the file in the console it receives the answer but it is not defined

```js
<template>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <form
      @submit.prevent="submit"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      class="largeur80 my-5 shadow bordurePost bordureRond"
    >
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="text-primary" for="titre">Titre du post</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          name="titre"
          placeholder="title..."
          v-model.trim="$v.titre.$model"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="error" v-if="!$v.titre.required && submitStatus === 'ERROR'">
        Field is required
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="text-primary" for="description">Description</label>
        <textarea
          class="form-control"
          name="description"
          rows="3"
          placeholder="Décrire le post..."
          v-model.trim="$v.description.$model"
        ></textarea>
      </div>
      <div
        class="error"
        v-if="!$v.description.required && submitStatus === 'ERROR'"
      >
        Field is required
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="text-primary" for="image_link"
          >Ajouter une image ou multimedia</label
        >
        <input type="file" ref="file" class="file-input" @change="upload" />
      </div>
      <!--
      <div
        class="error"
        v-if="!$v.image_link.required && submitStatus === 'ERROR'"
      >
        Field is required
      </div>
      -->
      <div
        class="form-group row d-flex align-item-center justify-content-center"
      >
        <div class="col-sm-10 ">
          <button
            type="submit"
            class="bg-light btn btn-outline-primary"
            :disabled="submitStatus === 'PENDING'"
          >
            Publier !
          </button>
          <p class="typo__p" v-if="submitStatus === 'OK'">
            Thanks for your submission!
          </p>
          <p class="typo__p" v-if="submitStatus === 'ERROR'">
            Please fill the form correctly.
          </p>
          <p class="typo__p" v-if="submitStatus === 'ERROR SERVEUR'">
            erreur serveur:Le mot de passe ou l'email ne correponde pas OU
            server HS !
          </p>
          <p class="typo__p" v-if="submitStatus === 'PENDING'">Sending...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { required, maxLength } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "envoyer",

  data() {
    return {
      file: "",
      titre: "",
      description: "",
      image_link: null || "",
      user_id: localStorage.getItem("userId") || null,
      submitStatus: null,
    };
  },
  validations: {
    titre: { required, maxLength: maxLength(100) },
    description: { required, maxLength: maxLength(500) },
    image_link: {},
  },

  methods: {
    upload() {
      this.file = this.$refs.file.files[0];
      console.log(this.file);
    },

    submit() {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", this.file);

      console.log("requete ver serveur!");
      this.$v.$touch();
      if (this.$v.$invalid) {
        this.submitStatus = "ERROR";
        console.log("A echouer informations non complete!");
      } else {
        // do your submit logic here
        console.log("En attente");
        this.submitStatus = "PENDING";

        axios
          .post("http://localhost:3000/poste", this.file)
          .then((response) => {
            (this.submitStatus = "OK"), console.log(response);
            console.log(this.file);
            //this.$router.go("/post");
          })

          .catch(
            (error) => (
              (this.submitStatus = "ERROR SERVEUR"), console.log(error)
            )
          );
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

here is a photo of the application

[image]

and here is the middleware with multer it is also in the route post call and in app.use I use a path for the static images file that I created in the back

```js
// variable module npm multer
const multer = require("multer");

const MIME_TYPES = {
  "image/jpg": "jpg",
  "image/jpeg": "jpg",
  "image/png": "png",
};

// logique pour les stockage telechargements de fichiers et modification d image avec multer

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, callback) => {
    callback(null, "images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, callback) => {
    const name = file.originalname.split(" ").join("_");
    const extension = MIME_TYPES[file.mimetype];
    callback(null, name + Date.now() + "." + extension);
  },
});

module.exports = multer({ storage: storage }).single("image");
```

how to recover this image file and already receive it to the server with my configuration ???? thank you for answering me

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you did not send the `formData` and sent `this.file` instead on the axios call.
This is what you worte in your post:

```
axios
  .post("http://localhost:3000/poste", this.file)
```

This is what to do:

```
axios
  .post("http://localhost:3000/poste", formData)
```

[UPDATE]

It alse seems you should do `formData.append('image', this.file)` because on the backend you used "image" as filename:

```js
module.exports = multer({ storage: storage }).single("image");
```

Comment: here the picture  on the top after add formdata but nots goods i don t know what s the problem ??

Comment: I don't see any picture, maybe pictures don't show in comments?

Comment: okay it's in the post, I see it now. I think it's an issue on the backend.
Unfortunately I don't know Multer + I'm not a NodeJs dev. But my guess is, the field name expected in multer is not the good one?

Comment: here I added it in the post one now

Comment: I think I got what's happening, so basically from what I read here https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/file-upload-with-multer-in-node--cms-32088, you did multer( ... )..single("image") but this is not how you called the file in the formData, you used formData.append('file', this.file) instead of formData.append('image', this.file).
Do you see what I mean?

Comment: yes i receive the picture now i add the response picture but the file name is not send ?? et en console this.file is undefined i dont understand but the picture into the folder images i add the picture commande line and the frontend

Comment: Perfect, then make sure to mark my answer as correct please if it resolved your issue.